# Bootstrap 3.0 Centered Main Content with right Sidebar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to have a centered main content div along with a right sidebar using Bootstrap 3.0.
I have tried the following code to achieve this.

[BootPly](http://www.bootply.com/YPXoOzmZJc)

But when i resize the browser to shorter width, the sidebar gets pushed down and also the main content get wider. Is this behavior expected of bootstrap ? Do i need to add col-xs* to accommodate the shorter width ?

I am wondering if this is the correct way to achieve this design ?

Thanks !

Comment: what do you want to happen when screen width gets smaller? keep the main content and sidebar side-by-side, or bring the sidebar on top of the main content?

Comment: I would like to have the main content not change its width.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is default behaviour. Bootstrap 3 was built with "mobile first" in mind, so the layout is responsive by default. You can achieve this effect by writing a custom grid and not using the Bootstrap column classes, like `col-sm-6` and so on.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="content">
                Main Content
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar">
                Side bar
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then write some css. This is just an example, and you should customise to fit your own needs.

```
.sidebar { width: 33.3%; }
.content { width: 66.6%; }
```

You can fit two columns on the smallest screen size, but it's unlikely that this is what you are after. On small screens there's very little space for any substantial content to fit into two columns.

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
    Main Content
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
    Side bar
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed correct that this is a feature of bootstrap :) You're also correct on using `.col-xs-*` to achieve your planned design. To add to what you're trying to do, (just in case you haven't tried this already) you can also combine the grid classes in order to accommodate the different screen sizes.

Here's an example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    </div>
</div>
```

Goodluck! :)